# Django: Query gives zero results after first match in for loop

Tags: django

The following code works fine until the filter gets first match(es). After that on the following runs in the for loop, the query always returns 0. If in that result object would be a match for the next row also, it doesn't even see that, so I don't see this being a cache issue (which might have been far fetched anyhow).

```
 for row in self._ordr.OrderRows.SalesOrderRow:
     available = row.Row_amount - Slot.objects.filter(rows_ids=row.Row_id).count()

     if available > 0 or row.Row_id in self.instance.rows_ids:
          # some code
```

Any ideas what am I doing wrong here?

This is the models code on that rows_ids.

```
from django.db import models
from django_mysql.models import ListCharField

class Slot(models.Model):
rows_ids = ListCharField(base_field=models.IntegerField(), size=10, max_length=(10 * 21), null=True)
```

Comment: Would you mind to share your models code?

Comment: I added the models code to the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went through the documentation once more, and apparently it's a ListCharField based issue. To find a match in all the options in it, you shouldn't compare it directly to the field, but rather to field__contains. So the correct code is:

```
for row in self._ordr.OrderRows.SalesOrderRow:
     available = row.Row_amount - Slot.objects.filter(rows_ids__contains=row.Row_id).count()

     if available > 0 or row.Row_id in self.instance.rows_ids:
          # some code
```

Finally got it to work with this.